# Netsuite - Add the Manufacturer & Display Name to the inventory count Item List

Tags: netsuite, inventory

I am trying to add the Manufacturer and Display name to the Inventory Count as columns on the Item list.

I found that there is **Enhancement #** **235992** - Be able to Customize Create Inventory Count Page > Add Additional Columns/Filters

Has anyone found a workaround?  Would it be possible to run a script that would show those columns when you open an inventory Count form?

[Screenshot of Netsuite Inventory Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gasH3.png)